# Looking to pinpoint the what's wrong in my SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

(THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE.  READ CAREFULLY!)
‌I have two tables:

1. `ZIPCodes`- ‌contains all the zipcodes of the USA with latitude and longitude.
2. `usersearch_answers`- has a zipcode column with the zipcodes where users live.

‌‌I want to have two variables: `zipcode` that the user can specify, and a `distance` in miles that a user can also specify.

‌The results should return anyone within the radius of the zipcode that the user specified.

Now, the query below works as expected only when there's at least one person in the users table with the zipcode that was specified.

Nothing returns if the zipcode that entered is not contained in the table, even if there are nearby zipcodes.

Can someone please pinpoint for me in this code where the problem is?  What do I need to do in order to get the rest of the zipcodes working? Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```
$data_query = mysqli_query($conn, "
SELECT ZIPCodes.zipcode, usersearch_answers.username,
       (3959 * acos(cos(radians(ZIPCodes.latitude)) *
       cos(radians(center.latitude)) *
       cos(radians(ZIPCodes.longitude ) -
       radians(center.longitude)) +
       sin(radians(ZIPCodes.latitude)) *
       sin(radians(center.latitude)))) AS distance 
FROM
( 
    ( 
        SELECT usersearch_answers.username,
            usersearch_answers.zipcode,
            ZIPCodes.latitude,
            ZIPCodes.longitude 
        FROM
        (
            usersearch_answers JOIN ZIPCodes ON usersearch_answers.zipcode = ZIPCodes.zipcode
        )    
        WHERE (ZIPCodes.zipcode='33133')
    ) center, ZIPCodes
) INNER JOIN usersearch_answers ON ZIPCodes.zipcode = usersearch_answers.zipcode
WHERE (usersearch_answers.username <> '$userLoggedIn') 
HAVING (distance < 5000)
ORDER BY distance");
```

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question.
Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community.

Comment: "READ CAREFULLY!" ? - surely that's what you should be doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is this line:

```
usersearch_answers JOIN ZIPCodes ON usersearch_answers.zipcode = ZIPCodes.zipcode
```

The keyword JOIN by itself (no LEFT or RIGHT) implies that this is an INNER JOIN.  So in order for there to be a record returned then it has to include zip AND the user.

If you want it to return even if there is no user then change that line to:

```
usersearch_answers RIGHT JOIN ZIPCodes ON usersearch_answers.zipcode = ZIPCodes.zipcode
```

Full query:

```
$data_query = mysqli_query($conn, "
SELECT ZIPCodes.zipcode, usersearch_answers.username,
       (3959 * acos(cos(radians(ZIPCodes.latitude)) *
       cos(radians(center.latitude)) *
       cos(radians(ZIPCodes.longitude ) -
       radians(center.longitude)) +
       sin(radians(ZIPCodes.latitude)) *
       sin(radians(center.latitude)))) AS distance 
FROM
( 
    ( 
        SELECT usersearch_answers.username,
            ZIPCodes.zipcode,
            ZIPCodes.latitude,
            ZIPCodes.longitude 
        FROM
        (
            usersearch_answers RIGHT JOIN ZIPCodes ON usersearch_answers.zipcode = ZIPCodes.zipcode
        )    
        WHERE (ZIPCodes.zipcode='33133')
    ) center, ZIPCodes
) INNER JOIN usersearch_answers ON ZIPCodes.zipcode = usersearch_answers.zipcode
WHERE (usersearch_answers.username <> '$userLoggedIn') 
HAVING (distance < 5000)
ORDER BY distance");
```

Comment: Thank you Indiri!  That was it!  I was missing the word 'RIGHT,' and I could've sworn that I had tried that!  Thank you so much, I am so grateful to you for your kind response.  You're the BEST!!!!!